# NSMutableArray count says that only one element in, but they are in fact more

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml-parsing, nsdictionary

I'm trying get from NSDictionary needed data. NSDictionary looks like:

```
{
    result =     {
        id =         (
                        {
                text = 1;
            },
                        {
                text = 2;
            }
        );
        name =         (
                        {
                text = "name 1";
            },
                        {
                text = "name 2";
            }
        );
}
```

The problem is - that can be single element of "name" or "id", and when it's single, error occurred. I'm trying a lot of solutions to fix it, one of those:

```
 NSDictionary * dict0=[_xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"result"];

    ID =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [ID addObject:[[dict0 valueForKey:@"id"] valueForKey:@"text"]];

    name =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [name addObject:[[dict0 valueForKey:@"name"] valueForKey:@"text"]];
```

When I print ID and name arrays, I'm see:

for ID:

```
(
(1,
 2
)
)
```

for name:

```
(
(
"name 1",
"name 2"
)
)
```

But Xcode show name.count = 1, and when I'm trying implement cellForRowAtIndexPath with id and name, error occurred:

```
 [__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10b102830
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'
```

How can I fix it, that my code will work  fine when single element and more?

Answer (score 2):

The data structure you displayed at first looks like it's an outer dictionary that contains dictionaries, who's items contain arrays that in turn contain more dictionaries.

Your code to fetch the text object from ID would look like this:

```
//get the dictionary at key "result"
NSDictionary result = _xmlDictionary[@"result"]; 

//Get the array at key "id" in result dict
NSArray the_id = result[@"id"];  

//Get the object at index 0 in the array 
NSDictionary objAtIndex0 = the_id[0];  

//Get the object at key "text" in the dictionary
NSString *text = objAtIndex0[@"text"];
```

Or, all together in 1 line:

```
NSString *text = _xmlDictionary[@"result"][@"id"][0][@"text"];
```

Comment: but if I have more than one elements of "id" and "name"?